# Replace substring in GeoJSON for popup window Leaflet

Tags: function, replace, leaflet, substring

Have looked into lots of questions about replacing substrings, but none of the examples has been working for me. I have a string in geojson (feature.properties.openingHours), this properties has "Mon, Fri, Sat, Sun" together with times "00:00-24:00 Mon-Sun" etc. I need to change the weekdays to local language for the popup when a "click" occur on a point in the Leaflet map. The string can hold several opening hours like "00:00-20:00 Mon-Fri 08:00-20:00 Sat 08:00-18:00 Sun"

This is the latest I have tried and I get the error "days not defined", is this wrong way doing it, or what is missing?

Result should be from "00:00-24:00 Mon-Sun" => "00:00-24:00 Mån-Sön"

```
    function openingHours(feature, latlng){ 
    var days = feature.properties.openingHours
        days = days.replace(/Mon/g, 'Mån')
        days = days.replace(/Fri/g, 'Fre')
        days = days.replace(/Sat/g, 'Lör')
        days = days.replace(/Sun/g, 'Sön');
    };

geoLayer = L.geoJson(json, {
     
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.shapeMarker(latlng, {radius: 7, color: '#b30000', fillOpacity: 0.7, weight: 2,  shape: 'square'})
    },

onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    var popupText = '';
    popupText += (feature.properties.openingHours) ? '<br></b><i>Öppettider:</i>': '';
    popupText += (feature.properties.openingHours) ? '<br></b><i>' + openingHours(days) + '</i><br>': '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass to the `openingHours` function a undefined variable.

Change your code to:

```
   function openingHours(feature){ 
    var days = feature.properties.openingHours
        days = days.replace(/Mon/g, 'Mån')
        days = days.replace(/Fri/g, 'Fre')
        days = days.replace(/Sat/g, 'Lör')
        days = days.replace(/Sun/g, 'Sön');
        return days;
    };

geoLayer = L.geoJson(json, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
         return new L.shapeMarker(latlng, {radius: 7, color: '#b30000', fillOpacity: 0.7, weight: 2,  shape: 'square'})
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        var popupText = '';
        popupText += (feature.properties.openingHours) ? '<br></b><i>Öppettider:</i>': '';
        popupText += (feature.properties.openingHours) ? '<br></b><i>' + openingHours(feature) + '</i><br>': '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Small changes makes a huge different! Excellent!!